# Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online) not showing GitHub repository type

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to setup an integration between my GitHub and VSTS account.
I'm creating a build definition to build and deploy my code to my azure web app. From all the things I've read online (I've been trying to make this work for at least some 3h now) this should be so simple I'm reconsidering calling myself a developer... =/

I've added the Service Endpoint:

[image]

But it doesn't show up at the build definition:

[image]

The other service endpoints for azure work fine, I'm able to set them at the build definition, but the GitHub just won't work! I've tried signing out, using chrome's private window, removing and re-adding the endpoint, using IE, nothing makes that damn thing show up as an option in the dropdown.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT - ScreenCast**

http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cDif6XiUSZ

After 3 days and no answer from MS I kept trying to figure it out and it seems this account is running on an old version.(?)

I have another account that's working fine and I started to compare both, here's why I think that:

### Different versions

[image]

### no online column and different header (Account profile vs Account/acc_name)

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Can you try cleaning the browser cache file? And when you create a new build definition, does "GitHub" display on the "Settings" dialog?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I've tried all of that... I even used different browsers in different OSes (Mac / win). Thanks

Comment: The option does not display when create new build definition too?

Comment: By the way, are you using Visual Studio Team Service? Or On-premise TFS?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT no, I even opened a support ticket... Crazy... Anyway, I'm using VSTS and no, it doesn't show up even if it's a new build definition. Thanks again

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I'm gonna create a screencast so you can see it. Just a sec.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT please, check the screen cast I just posted. Thanks.

Comment: I see it. Do you open the web portal from xxx.visualstudio.com? It also missed "Release" tab after "Test" tab in the UI.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT yes, I open it through xxx.vs...com and yes, no release tab. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Please submit a feedback on MS Connect Page: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I will... my ticket is still open after 3 days. So much for 8 biz hours... Thanks.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT if you can, check my updated question. I think my VSO account might be running in an old server. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are right that your account is running in an old server.
I created one in India South and experienced the same behavior.

Then I deleted it and created one in South US and I can see my GitHub repository.